# Static anonymous function vs normal anonymous function

Tags: php

What is the difference between the following two anonymous functions? Static does not seem to do what I initially thought (which is executing it only once like rust constant functions).

```php
$func1 = function () {
    return true;
}

$func2 = static function () {
    return true
}
```

Comment: _"executing it only once and caching the result"_ ...where did you get that idea from exactly? I'd be fascinated to know. I suggest reading the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php . Then let us know if you don't understand anything from that article. You can also find more in-depth explanations in quite a few others places, such as https://www.exakat.io/en/5-usages-of-static-keyword-in-php/ - it has a specific section on static closures.

Comment: That is static methods and properties. I am talking about static *anyonymous functions*.

Comment: Also, I was referring to this https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/9msqfn/const_fn_soon_on_stable_rust/, a lot of languages have this capability. Hence I thought, perhaps PHP does some trickery with opcache here.

Comment: "I am talking about static anyonymous functions"...that's why I included the second link in my comment which talks about closures specifically. Anyway, don't assume that languages do the same things or have the same capabilities, or that keywords mean the same thing. If they did, there'd be far less point in having lots of different languages. Research, instead, to understand the real capabilities rather than the assumed ones.

Comment: So basically, its making the anonymous function contextless? I'd assume this only makes sense for e.g. the garbage collector, as it will avoid keeping references.

Comment: essentially yes - and this is somewhat similar to other static properties and functions, if you think about it. It makes sense if you only have a static class to start with, and you don't _need_ a context, or as the article says it may avoid leaks, or could allow the $this variable to be filled by another context later - I can't think of a use case for that right now but I'm sure there will be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using static anonymous functions, you don’t propagate the context of creation with the closure, so `$this` won’t be available anymore. This may avoid leaks, or will allow the $this variable to be filled by another context later.

Reference: https://www.exakat.io/en/5-usages-of-static-keyword-in-php/